# error JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject android studio y google script

Tags: android-studio, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, jsonobject, jsonarray

estoy realizando una APP que lee un jsonarray de google script, (ver imagenes adjuntas).
pero al leer el jsonarray la app muestra el error de que no se puede convertir a jsonobject.

Lo mas probable es que formato del jsonarray este malo, hay alguna forma de verificar que el array este escrito correctamente?.

[image: error de la app al leer el JSON de la pagina web]
[image: JSON Array devuelto por la pagina web]

Comment: Estás recibiendo un JSONArray, no un JSONObject, por tanto la lectura debe ser distinta.

Answer (score 0):

Si recibes la data, lo mas seguro es la estructura de tu petición, esta intenta recibir un JsonObject y sin embargo recibe un JsonArray. Deberias de cambiarlo a que reciba un JsonArray y luego eso lo conviertes a varios JsonObjects.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75F4ZqotHTU&list=PLAg6Lv5Bbjjeh7m51aXdKcdWf6kMKylzN&index=5

Answer (score 0):

el array debe estar sin corchetes . es decir asi:
{"NOMBRE":"GERSON HERRERA","CEDULA":"1042452724","SECCION":"TALLER"}